# CISCO developer routers/ firmware

Tags: cisco, router

I was wandering if there are any CISCO routers and firmware for purchase or download for developers so I could test my implementations on them.

I am developing a firmware plugin to increase security on dual stack methodologies. Therefore i need a router that would grant me access to its firmware so that i could alter it to plugin my solution :)

Comment: You can purchase a Cisco 2600 router for less than $50 USD on EBay...

Comment: @MikePennington hey thanks for the reply again :) is that a developer version? do i have access to its firmware? :)

Comment: Normally Cisco routers include a firmware load when you buy them on ebay... ask the seller if you have questions.  There is no such thing as a developer version of cisco ios...

Comment: @MikePennington thank you very much :) i need the firmware cause i need to addon some functionalities to it myself.. do you know which language it is written in?

Comment: @Hasitha Cisco does not allow users to access/modify their software/firmware on the device.  It is Cisco proprietary code.  You configure settings on the device, but not the underlying operating system or firmware.

Comment: @BrettLykins Thank you for that information :) do you know a type router that would allow access to its firmware.like a developer version. I have heard that such exists but could not find any..

Comment: I don't know where specifically, but they should be able to help you out in [here](http://developer.cisco.com/)

Comment: I think the best you could do is to look for Cisco ONE programming kit. Otherwise, as Brett said, Cisco does not provide access to its software. Via ONE programming kit, Cisco would be providing APIs to program the router in some of the new releases. Here is a link: http://www.cisco.com/web/solutions/trends/open_network_environment/index.html . You will have to check which releases would support ONE pk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best you could do is to look for Cisco ONE programming kit. Otherwise, as Brett said, Cisco does not provide access to its software. Via ONE programming kit, Cisco would be providing APIs to program the router in some of the new releases.

Here are some links:

http://www.cisco.com/web/solutions/trends/open_network_environment/index.html
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/iosswrel/onepk.html

You will have to check which releases would support ONE pk.